# nginx request should go multiple locations

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am a newbie about nginx. I read some books but i did not find the answer. 
I found this but it is not my problem.(in my case , request go to first/location and then second/location)

```
location ~ ^/(first/location|second/location)/  {
...
}
```

Problem: i have several microservices. One of them is authentication service.Others are essential services. I want that when client create a request over the nginx, nginx first go to authentication service and then essential service. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

First use

```
location authentication/location  {
...
}
```

for the authentication service.
At the end of the authentication set a redirect to

```
location essential_services/location  {
...
}
```

or to

```
location reject/location  {
...
}
```

Comment: Do you know the syntax. As i said i am newbie. I searched for redirect. I found "rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.essentialservice/$1 redirect;" How can  i use that?

Comment: You don't do the redirect in the nginx configuration, but in your authentication script.

Comment: Is it possible with nginx configuration?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. When you're authenticating a user by your authentication service, the script there will have to decide where the user has to be sent to. At that point in time the redirect must occur in your script.

Comment: You may redirect through the nginx configuration, but it is a redirect of an url, so the moment this url is being formed by your authentication service, you may better form the right url at once so you don't have to redirect by nginx

Comment: I have to use nginx configuration.

Comment: What does your authentication service do after it's finished? Is there a new url that's being served?

Comment: Almost nothing, it only returns "success" or "failure" and according to the return value request should be directed to essential service or login page via nginx.

Comment: Do I understand correct that the authentication script only returns a textstring "success" or "failure"? Nginx redirect/rewrite does not respond to that. My idea would be alter the authentication script so that it serves a url.